# Python - Why won't my request use the proxy provided and display my public IP instead

Tags: python, http, proxy, python-requests

So I am trying to implement a proxy service into my script however, after looking at different solutions, my script won't return the proxy's IP address.

Code:

```
import requests

http_proxy  = "http://181.59.126.156:8080"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
            }


r = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/", proxies=proxyDict)

print(r.text)
```

This returns my real public IP Address when I need it to return the proxies IP address to confirm the proxy is being used when making the HTTP request.

Ipify is the API I am using for testing purposes.

Any Help would be appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your proxy is routing only HTTP requests while your request is done over HTTPS.

To achieve what you want you will need to set up HTTPS proxy like so:

```
import requests

https_proxy  = "http://181.59.126.156:[https_proxy_port]"

proxyDict = { 
              "https"  : https_proxy, 
            }


r = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/", proxies=proxyDict)

print(r.text)
```